# on pushViewController AlphaComponent not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to push viewcontroller from NavigationController, and in viewcontroller I'm setting AlphaComponent for transparent effect, but it's not working. It's working with on presnt, but it's not working on Push, how to resolve this ?

```
    let vc = SGeoLocation(nibName: "SGeoLocation", bundle: nil)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: You doing this on transition state ?

Comment: why would you set modal presentation styles to view controller and push it on navigation controller later? What are you trying to achieve? do you wanna embed nav controller to View controller and present it modally??

Comment: let me guess you getting black background ?

Comment: yes, it's getting black @MohmmadS

Comment: are you trying to create popup ?

Comment: @KarthikMandava If you want to display a transparent effect View controller then you must be used **Present** it's not possible with **Push**

Comment: @KarthikMandava check my answer for explanation .

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is because of the hierarchy of your `UIViewcontrollers`

Let me explain shortly,

A `UINavigationController` is a **Last In first out** stack of `UIViewControllers`, 
When you push a `UIViewController` you  pushing it into the stack means there is nothing behind your `UIViewController` because the `UIWindow` hierarchy contains one element at the time inside the `UINavigationController`.

Check out this image, to explain what is Last in first out stack, consider this as your `UINavigationViewController` with its `UIViewControllers` as 
**Data elements**
[image]

Now why it works when you `present` the `UIViewController`, simply because you overlay your `UIViewController` on top of your current visible one.

Check this image of how presenting work.
[image]

**Wrapping up**:

When you set the `View.backgroundColor = .clear` while present you can see the behind of your present `UIViewController`, but when pushing you simply see black screen because there is nothing behind there.

**Short answer**: 
You can't see what's behind unless you present.

Comment: you can't and this explains why, you have to present,

Comment: i think that you want to have a popover that slides from the right on top of the scene  am i right ?

Comment: If you do want a transparent background can try setting window background color to clear. But this still won't overlay on top of the previous VC due to being a push segue.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initialising SelectGeoLocation's view is not loaded.

Have you tried putting self.view.alpha = xxx inside your SelectGeoLocation-ViewDidLoad ?

Comment: Please re-read your answer and format it well to fit the OP question + if you are not sure of the answer, perhaps you should post it as comment.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback